# Redireccion de todas las IP menos las definidas mediante web.config

Tags: web.config

Tengo un sitio web al cual le tengo que hacer algunas actualizaciones y necesito que todas las IP redireccionen a un html de aviso de que se está actualizando menos las que yo configure (las mías) para realizar los test correspondientes.
El problema es que tengo que hacerlo con el web.config porque por error en su momento seleccione un hosting bajo Windows.

¿Es posible? ¿Como podría hacerlo?

**Solucionado**

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la solución que encontraste como respuesta? Le puede servir a alguien más en un futuro

Comment: Agregue un archivo require en todos los php fuera del sitio (listas de precios, login, registro, activación de cuenta, etc) llamando a un pequeño php (de esta manera al dejar las tareas de mantenimiento, se edita una sola linea y se aplica a todos) donde redirecciono al index y para acceder genere un login alternativo.

No es para nada la solución que buscaba, pero frente a no encontrar solución, fue lo que se me ocurrió para hacer el mantenimiento durante el domingo y lunes (lunes feriado en Argentina)